# Create a JSON document from NSObject with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to create a **JSON** array of objects, to manipulate and save in UserPreferences after, like this:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "01",
    "title" : "Title"
  },
  {
    "id" : "02",
    "title": "Title 02"
  }
]
```

this is my NSObject class:

```
class Item: NSObject {
  var _id: String = ""
  var _title: String = ""

  var id: String {
    get {
        return _id
    }
    set {
        _id = newValue
    }
  }

  var title: String {
    get {
        return _title
    }
    set {
        _title = newValue
    }
  }

}
```

And I have this code to convert to JSON using **SwiftyJson**, but I cant make this like a array

```
var item: [Item] = ["array of itens already setted"]
var json: JSON = JSON([:])
for item in list {
   json["id"].string = item.id
   json["title"].string = item.title
}
```

This code return just the last item of array:

```
{
  "id" : "01",
  "title" : "Title"
}
```

Comment: Don't use backing stored properties and computed properties as an alibi not to write an initializer. That's horrible. Consider that a standard initializer requires less code. And in Swift 4+ SwiftyJSON became obsolete in favor of the `Codable` protocol.

Comment: Why does `Item` extend `NSObject`? Why is it a class and not a struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies here , as loop iterates you are setting values in same object.

```
var item: [Item] = ["array of itens already setted"]
var json: [JSON] = [JSON([:])]. -----> this should be array not just object
for item in list {
   json["id"].string = item.id
   json["title"].string = item.title
}
```

**instead use this :**

```
var item: [Item] = ["array of itens already setted"]
var json: [JSON] = [JSON([:])]. -----> json array 
for item in list {
   let jsonTemp: JSON = JSON([:])
   jsonTemp["id"].string = item.id
   jsonTemp["title"].string = item.title
   json.append(jsonTemp)
}

print("[JSON OBJECT Count :: \(json.count), Informations are : \(json)]")
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with the var "json" is setting a empty object on begin of array "{ }", but the rest is awesome

Comment: I figure it out, this should be like this: var json: [JSON] = []

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that class `Item` adopts `Codable` protocol.
Then have `JSONEncoder` do the job. That way, you can even nest the resulting JSON inside more complex type.
Also check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) out for how to customize key names.

```
let items = [Item(), Item()]
items[0].id = "01"
items[0].title = "Title"
items[1].id = "02"
items[1].title = "Title 02"

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
print(String(data: try encoder.encode(items), encoding: .ascii)!)

/* result
[
  {
    "_id" : "01",
    "_title" : "Title"
  },
  {
    "_id" : "02",
    "_title" : "Title 02"
  }
]
*/
```